# Pandas groupby apply on one column and keeping the other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dummy df :

```
    name    value1    otherstuff1 otherstuff2 
0   Jack       1          1.19        2.39     
1   Jack       3          1.19        2.39
2   Luke       2          1.08        1.08  
3   Mark       4          3.45        3.45
4   Luke       1          1.08        1.08
```

I want to apply a complex function (not pertinent to explicit) to the value column over the grouped dataframe on 'name'. But I still want to keep track of the otherstuff column knowing that for each name, the 'otherstuffX' columns have the same value.

Expected output :

```
    name    value1    otherstuff1 otherstuff2 
0   Jack    184.2         1.19        2.39    
1   Luke    220.84        1.08        1.08  
2   Mark    0.58          3.45        3.45
```

Sample code that is working but makes otherstuff columns disappear :

```
df.groupby('name', sort=False)['value1'].apply(complex_function).reset_index()
```

What does work but I don't want to do :
Doing the above line then merging the other columns to the grouped dataframe.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `groupby().agg`:

```
df.groupby('name').agg({
   'value1': complex_function, 
   'otherstuff1': 'first', 
   'otherstuff2':'first'
})
```

Comment: In this case I like `d = {c: 'first' for c in df.columns} ; d['value1'] = complex_function; df.groupby('name').agg(d)` to handle all columns automatically ;)